# IIS - Change IP address - forbidden access

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am hosting several sites on IIS 7.5 on Server 2008 R2.

The server has a local IP address - 192.168.0.2. All port forwarding goes through the router and all works fine.

I have a license file for CUteEditor which is bound to our external IP address, meaning (i think) I need to change the bindings for each website so they are all  using the external IP.

I have gone to the network adapeter properties and added the second IP address.

The problem is, when I change the IP address from the internal to external IP in the bindings, I get the following error -

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
Any ideas on this would be very apreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you really hitting your IIS site?   There's not a lot of information about your configuration here, but what appears to be happening is that the router that is port forwarding is expecting to find the site at 192.168.0.2, and now that you've un-bound your site from that IP, it's likely finding the default site at that address, and that is what is returning the 403s.   You should be able to verify this by checking the logs, which should show that some site other than the web site you're trying to configure is taking the requests and responding to them.

As to the correct configuration, it might behoove you to seek the advice of the CuteFTP people, and ask them for their instructions for implementation in a NAT environment.  I'm sure it's a configuration they're familiar with, as it would be required for any load-balanced site.

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple case of getting CuteEditor to change the IP on the license file.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.